# Hyundai Tucson 2005 intermittent AC

Tags: ac, intermittent-problems, tucson

I have a Hyundai Tucson 2005. Bought it recently. The AC gives cold air for some time (like 20-30 min) and then blows hot air. If I turn it off and turn on again, it will still give hot air. It may again give cold air after I turn if on after a long time. The Freon level is okay. What can be the problem and how do I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Is the condenser blocked?

Comment: Look for the compressor's clutch plate in front of the pulley (yours is a Denso btw, either the 10PA15C or the 10PA17C, pictures on the net don't show any thermal switch on its body). When you begin to feel the air becoming warm, check if it's still rotating (cycling, i.e. rotating for a certain time and then stopping for a certain time, then resuming rotation and so on, actually) or it has suddenly become completely stationary and won't rotate anymore.

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning. Check if the "hot air" also comes with a noticeable reduction in vent airflow vs "cold air".

Comment: How did you check to ensure the refrigerant is at the proper level? This is strange ... if there's one thing which always seems to work on a Hyundai, it's the AC! :o)

Comment: The only way of knowing if an ac system's refrigerant is at the proper level is evacuating the system and weighing what's been evacuated. Has this been done?

Comment: @SolarMike How do I check if the condenser is blocked or not?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I took it to a mechanic, he connected some gauge to it and read the meter.He said its not full but this isn't the problem.

Comment: @SulavTimsina by looking  : leaves, paper other rubbish - if air can’t get to it then it won’t cool...

Comment: @SolarMike Its not blocked. If it was blocked, it would not cool for the first time.

Comment: @SulavTimsina yes it would until it can’t get rid of any more heat - becomes what is called saturated ... left to cool down it starts working again...